# $wpdb Query Result not coming but in phpmyadmin it works

Tags: wpdb

Here is my query, when i run this in PHP file its returns `NULL` but same query in Phpmyadmin return row.

Even I tried with `$wpdb->get_row()` and `$wpdb->get_col()` but the result is same for all.

```
include 'wp-config.php';
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_order_transaction WHERE order_id=1431");
var_dump($result);
```

can any one tell me where is my mistake.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @N00b : no $wpdb can read data from custom table also, please review : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Yup, I rechecked it from codex.

Comment: Why you are including `include 'wp-config.php';` config file ?

Comment: @Sumit actually its custom separate page so its required; otherwise it shows fatal error for Call to a member function get_results()

Comment: Then it is not the right way to include the WordPress. Search the site you will see how you can load WordPress in a separate file.

Comment: Include wp-load rather than wp-config

Comment: @Sumit yes that might be wrong method, but without the same part of code not working in functions.php.

Comment: @TimMalone tried but returns same result

Comment: I just tested the same code, and it is working. You must test it with clean install.

Comment: yes strange @Sumit in my localhost its not working but same code working on live well..! anyways Thanks your advice is better to include file in proper way.

Comment: Hi @user2134, would you like to post an answer following up on this solution, to include the files the right way? Then this question can be marked as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the "wp-load.php" file at the top of the code